# Analytical rotation from 3 epipolar point correspondences

Tags: math, computer-vision, computational-geometry, rotational-matrices, analytical

I have 3 epipolar point correspondences, i.e. three `({x1, y1, 1}, {x2, y2, 1})` constructs. Actually, I only have `(x1, y1, y2)`, because `x2` contains huge error. These coordinates are already centered and normalized. Given 3D rotation matrix `RotM`, here is how I compute residual for one point:

```
residual(RotM) = y2' - y2
  where
    rotated = RotM . {x1, y1, 1}
    {x2', y2', 1} = rotated / rotated[3]
```

Surely, I can numerically optimize for these 3 residuals and get `RotM`, because it also has 3 degrees of freedom. But I want to get rotations analytically.

So the question is, given three `(x1, y1, y2)` triplets, what is the formula to compute rotation matrix? I would also be satisfied with Euler angles or quaternions.

Notes:

1. Rotation is small. Precisely, it is acceptable to throw away cubic terms of Teylor series for Euler angles.
2. Wolfram Mathematica refuses to solve this.
3. If I'm not mistaken, such transform is called "perspective transform".

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this problem is underdetermined with only three points. There is a fourth degree of freedom hidden in the normalization.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Taking my weird notation a bit further, here is one equation:
`(RotM[:,2] . {x1, y1, 1}) / (RotM[:,3] . {x1, y1, 1}) == y2`.
As you can see, there is only rotation matrix involved, and it has 3 degrees of freedom, so I need 3 such equations to solve the system. If you are saying that there may be several solutions (a finite number), then I just want them all. This case is also acceptable.

Comment: @NicoSchertler In what normalization does the fourth degree of freedom hide?

Comment: `rotated / rotated[3]`. Since you don't have a concrete correspondence but just "this point must lie on this ray". It is not really a degree of freedom, though. And since you only have the x-coordinate of the target, it is more like "this point must lie somewhere on this plane". So basically, you define three planes and want to find a rotation that maps each source point onto the corresponding plane. There is very likely more than one rotation doing that.

Comment: And by more than one, I mean potentially infinitely many.